# Dynamic filter expression in angularjs filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a array of object say persons, the person object has properties like name, age, gender etc.  and i have a select for selection of property from person object. i want to filter array based on the property selected and input from textbox.

```
     <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" >

            <select ng-model="filterBy" ng-options=" p for p in person"  ng-init='person= ["name","age","gender"]' >  </select>

            <input type="text" ng-model="filterAs"> </input>


         <table>
       <tr>      
       <td>Name</td>
       <td>Age</td>
       <td>Group</td>
       </tr>  

       <tr  ng-repeat=" person in persons | filter:{  filterBy : filterAs   }  ">   
       <td> {{ person.Name }} </td>
       <td> {{ person.Age}} </td>
       <td> {{ person.Group}} </td>   
       </tr> 
       </table>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps
View:

```
<select ng-model="key" ng-options=" key as key for (key,val) in persons[0]"  >  </select>
            <input ng-if ="key=='Name'" type="text" ng-model=search.Name> </input>
            <input ng-if ="key=='Age'"  type="text" ng-model=search.Age> </input>
            <input ng-if ="key=='Group'" type="text" ng-model=search.Group> </input>
         <table>
       <tr>
       <td ng-repeat= "p in person">{{p}}</td>
       </tr>  

       <tr  ng-repeat=" person in persons | filter:search">   
       <td> {{ person.Name }} </td>
       <td> {{ person.Age}} </td>
       <td> {{ person.Group}} </td>   
       </tr> 
       </table>
```

Controller:

```
controller("HelloController", function($scope) {

        $scope.persons=[
                        {Name:"vin",Age:"25",Group:"A"},
                        {Name:"Gok",Age:"26",Group:"B"}]
        $scope.key="Name"
        $scope.search={}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code should meet your requirements. [Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3534fHG0RReIZxykxoRr?p=preview)

```
</head>
<body ng-app="selectExample">
  <script>
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.colors = [
      {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'white', shade:'light'},
      {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'blue', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
    ];
    $scope.test=[
      {value:'name'},
      {value:'shade'}
      ]
    $scope.myColor = $scope.colors[2]; // red
    $scope.shownameandcolour=function() {

    }   
  }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">



  Color (null not allowed):
  <select ng-model="myColor1" ng-options="t.value for t in test"  ng-change="shownameandcolour()"></select><br>
<br/>

  <ul> 
  <div ng-if="myColor1.value=='name'">
  <input ng-model="nameModel"><br>
    <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="n in colors | filter:nameModel">
      {{n.name}}
    </li>
  </div>

    <div ng-if="myColor1.value=='shade'">
    <input ng-model="shadeModel"><br>
          <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="n in colors | filter:shadeModel">
      {{n.shade}}
    </li>
    </div>
  </ul>

</div>
</html>
```

Comment: example : select name or phone from dropDowm as selection critera then name or phone into serach box. properties like name ,phone ,age goes into dropdown box. and vinod patidar or khalid Hussain goes into search box. in your code vinod patidar or khalid hussain goes into drop down that's not tried to do !